# How to connect Visual Studio 2019 to TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio Professional 2019 looks to be all set for use of Azure DevOps.

We are using Azure DevOps but also have a large code base still in TFS.

I was using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (with TFS) but it seemed this was a 90 day trial.

I have now been issued with Visual Studio Professional 2019.

I should be able to connect Visual Studio Professional 2019 to TFS also ?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Richard suggested:

Team | Manage Connections then click on manage connections, from where you can connect to servers. "Connect to a Project" form/dialog ..

thanks for this comment !

i.e. in Visual Studio Pro 2019, the option is "Add Azure DevOps Server" even though wanting to add TFS server.

i.e.

[image]

In Visual Studio Pro 2017, it looks like this:

[image]

At first I have tried (successfully) File, Source Control menu options.
i.e. File | Source Control | Advanced | Open From Server ..

Question then was: "How do I switch Visual Studio Pro 2019 from TFS back to Azure DevOps?"

I have been using Git Gui and Git Bash for working with Azure DevOps so this wasn't so important.

I worked out how to switch between TFS and Azure DevOps projects also via use of this dialog form:

[image]

Comment: The correct answer to connect to one or more TFS/Dev Ops Servers is: Team | Manage Connections  then click on manage connections, from where you can connect to servers.

Comment: Thanks Richard - I tried this first but somehow failed to get Visual Studio to connect to TFS this way. (maybe I was supplying server / URL in an incorrect form).. I can see both TFS server and dev.azure.com under "Connect to a Project" dialog form now.

Comment: I also noted that when installing Visual Studio 2019, install process doesn't pick up workspace settings from Visual Studio 2017. i.e. have to recreate workspace(s) via Manage Workspaces after install.

Comment: I can use the "Connect to a Project" dialog form to switch between being connected to a TFS project and being connected to an Azure DevOps project.

Comment: `Add Azure DevOps Server even though wanting to add TFS server.` Actually there are the same thing,  Azure DevOps Server previously known as Team Foundation Server (TFS). We change the name since 2019 version, we now say Azure DevOps Server 2019 instead of TFS 2019. Besides, we also rename VSTS , and call it Azure DevOps Service at present.

Comment: Workspaces are picked up when you connect to that team project on a DevOps server (Azure or local).