# "Best Practices" doc for Devs reconfiguring Team Explorer when migrating Collection to new server?

Tags: azure-devops

I am planning to soon migrate a couple of Collections from a on premises TFS 2017 server to a on premises Azure DevOps 2019 server. These collections have multiple Git repos, no older VSTS style code repos.

I've found all sorts of good documents covering how to migrate the collection- and I am able to do that with ease. I took snapshots of my old and new servers and did a temporary test move over a weekend, everything came up just fine. I then reverted to the snapshots.

Does anyone know of a good document or URL for me to provide as instructions to my 20+ developers for them to reconfigure their Team Explorer in Visual Studio? The Collections on the old server will be detached, so there's no need for them to continue to have the old server configured. I don't want anyone to have to completely switch to the new server in a way where they lose any git branches that they only have local (not pushed up to the server.)

I myself only use TortoiseGit to interact with the git repos. I can see in my git repos, I go to the .git folder and change the URL in the file named "config" and the repo is switched over painlessly.

Almost all of the devs only use Team Explorer. If anyone knows of a good guide that I can walk them through with to make the switch from within Team Explorer instead of having to edit text files and registry keys, I appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for guides to connect your devs' Team Explorer in Visual Studio to the projects in the new on premises Azure DevOps 2019 server.

You can check the documents provided in Microsoft site [Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer).

For more detailed steps you can check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297628/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2019-to-tfs).

You can ask your devs to follow the steps in above thread to add the URL of the new server to Team Explorer. Then they can switch to code repo of new server.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Lindeman are the documents in above links what you are looking for?