# Source control explorer in Visuak Studio 2022 Community?

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2022

I want to unlock files from my solution explorer, but on the Microsoft Docs, it says i need to use the Source Control Explorer. However, it doesnt appear in my Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Please help.

[no sce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppDLT.png)

Comment: I have struck this before. You need to connect to the TFS server before this window ever shows anywhere (which I found really frustrating). I don't have a windows computer here to verify, but this feels very familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297628/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2019-to-tfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the "**Source control explorer**" is only applied to TFVC repositories. So, we have to connect to an Azure DevOps server(TFS) TFVC repository first.

Please follow below steps to show the "**Source control explorer**" in VS 2022 Community:

1. **View** -> **Team Explorer**
   [image]
2. **Manage Connections** -> **Connect to a project**
   [image]
3. Add an Azure DevOps server (TFS) -> Select a **TFVC** project repo -> **Connect**
   [image]
4. After that, go to **View** -> **Other Windows** to check the **Source control explorer** option.
   [image]